# How to select not null values from mysql table using pdo in php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a base class for all my CRUD purposes. I have a method to create an array from all the input and table row parameters passed in the method to be executed in $query->execute. For that reason I was wondering if the below format will work.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE row = :row');
$query->execute(array(':row' => NOT NULL));
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE row is NOT NULL?

Comment: Yes, but for specific reasons I want to fetch the data using the format demonstrated above

Comment: so you should post these reasons in the question to make it sensible